# How to write a generic update trigger for PostgreSQL view without known columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, postgresql-triggers

I'm using a PostgreSQL view to simulate a legacy table that has since been split into two separate tables, so we can maintain backwards compatibility with a range of services. The goal is essentially for this view to function transparently as if it was the original table before the split. Using an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger I've been able to handle inserts into the two tables pretty easily.

However I'm struggling to figure out how to write an `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` trigger, because I don't know which columns will be changed in any one request (I'm using sequelize so I don't really have any way of controlling what the requests are going to be, it could be `SET` a single column, it could be all of them). All examples I've found online seem to be updating known fields (either some meta-column related to the query or knowing what the shape of the update is going to be).

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_legacy_table_trigger()
RETURNS trigger AS $$
  BEGIN
    UPDATE table_a SET ??? WHERE id = NEW.id;
    UPDATE table_b SET ??? WHERE table_a_id = NEW.id; 
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

#### A few example cases:

Imagine:

- `legacy_table` is the name of the view
- `table_a` has the columns: `id`, `name`, `description`, `type`, `shared_column` and
- `table_b` has the columns: `id`, `table_a_id` (foreign key to `table_a`), `price`, `shared_column`.

**Example A:**

```
UPDATE legacy_table SET name="Test", price="10.00" WHERE id="123";
```

I'd expect the trigger to behave something like:

```
UPDATE table_a SET name="Test" WHERE id="123";
UPDATE table_b SET price="10.00" WHERE table_a_id="123";
```

**Example B:** it could also receive updates for only one table

```
UPDATE legacy_table SET price="10.00" WHERE id="123";
```

So we'd expect the trigger to behave like:

```
UPDATE table_b SET price="10.00" WHERE table_a_id="123";
```

**Example C:** perhaps a lot of columns in the one request

```
UPDATE legacy_table SET name="Test", price="10.00", description="A test", type="foo", shared_column="bar" WHERE id="123";
```

So the trigger should behave like:

```
UPDATE table_a SET name="Test", description="A test", type="foo", shared_column="bar" WHERE id="123";
UPDATE table_b SET price="10.00", shared_column="bar" WHERE table_a_id="123";
```

There might be cases where updates need to be made to both tables, but I don't believe there are any cases where the name of the column in the original `UPDATE` would be any different from the name of the columns in the new tables.

How would I go about writing this `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` trigger for these cases where I don't know explicitly what the UPDATE query will be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write the update statement for all the columns in your trigger function. Your trigger function will look like below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION update_legacy_table_trigger()
RETURNS trigger AS $$
  BEGIN
    UPDATE table_a SET name=new.name, description=new.description,type=new.type, shared_column=new.shared_column WHERE id = NEW.id;
    UPDATE table_b SET price=new.price, shared_columns=new.shared_columns WHERE table_a_id = NEW.id; 
    return null;
  END;
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and you have to write your trigger on your view as below:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER trg_update_legacy 
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
ON legacy_table
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_legacy_table_trigger();
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e18f452afea585b4be7751687d0329a4)

This will handle all the update cases because `NEW` will contain updated row and we are updating all the fields with the data of `NEW` row.

Comment: So it will just ignore fields that aren't included in the update. How simple. Thank you very much for your clear and comprehensive answer.